# How to force binary classification into multinomial classification

Tags: javascript, machine-learning, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

It's known that logistic regression for 2 classes will give us the probability for the first class and then using threshold we can decide which class it's in. Whereas, in multinomial classification, we get a vector probability that we can use.
I wanted to as if there is a way to treat the binomial classification problem as a multi-class problem and get the probability vector?

Answer (score 0):

You can use softmax function in logistic regression which gives the probability score for each class which total count is equals to one.

for reference you go through below answer  well explained 
https://www.quora.com/Why-is-it-better-to-use-Softmax-function-than-sigmoid-function